# Text between two images

Tags: html, css

The question is pretty self explanatory, I just want to know how to put text between two images with CSS. I've tried `position: absolute;` but it doesn't center it, I've tried `vertical-align: middle;` but it didn't do anything. [This](http://www.epilepticdev.tk) is the website, I'm hoping you guys can help.

If you don't understand the question, basically what I'm asking is how to do this:
-------webpage-------
[IMAGE] [TEXT] [IMAGE]
-------webpage-------

EDIT: It seems people didn't see my link to the website, either that or they can't view the source. Here's the code for the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Epileptic Development
    </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' />
</head>
<body>
    <div id='wrap'>
    <center>
        <div id="test">
            <img id='margin' src='ewd2.png' /><br />
            <img id='whale2' src='ewd.png' /><br />
            <div id="epileptic">
                <h1 id="header">
                    Epileptic<br /> Development
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div id='p'>
                <p>
                    Welcome to the official Epileptic Development website! <br />We'll be posting our news, games and projects here!                  
                </p>
                <p id='subreddit'>
                    <a href='http://www.reddit.com/r/sonl'>Our official sub reddit</a><br />
                </p>
                <p id='iTwitter'>
                    <a href='http://www.twitter.com/doorshaveknobs'>iPoisonxL's Twitter</a><br />
                </p>
                <p id='MTwitter'>
                    <a href='http://www.twitter.com/swagmaster63487'>MaXXik's Twitter</a><br />
                </p>
                <a href='/files/babyheadsmasher.zip'><img id='bhs' src='screen.png' title='Download BABY HEAD SMASHER!!' width='231' height='227' /></a>
                <a href='/files/sonl.zip'><img id='sonl' src='sonl.png' title='Download SoNL!!' width='231' height='227' /></a><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
    </div>
</body>
```

and here is the code for the CSS for the images/text:

```
#p {
font-family: inc;
font-size: 18;
border: 5px solid black;
border-top: 3px solid black;
border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
margin-top: 0px;
background-color: orange;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding: 10px;
padding-bottom: 284px;
}
img#margin {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
img#whale2 {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
#bhs {
    float: left;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin-left: 15px;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
#bhs:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
#sonl {
    float: right;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin-right: 15px;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
#sonl:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
#subreddit {
}
```

Note: I only put the relevant CSS.

Comment: Did you try float: left; ?? Remove position: absolute; first.

Comment: Hi, do you have the rest of the context ? Html code ? jsFiddle ?

Comment: google "3 column layout css" https://www.google.ca/search?q=3+column+layout+css&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=&rlz=&redir_esc=&ei=2UM3Ua35KeqGyAH02ICABw

Comment: no jquery suggestion? good, good...

Comment: I already know how to jQuery, I just don't feel like it's the correct way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="element">IMAGE</div>
    <div class="element">TEXT</div>
    <div class="element">IMAGE</div>
</div>

//CSS Code
.maindiv{width:600px;}
.element{width:200px; float:left;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misunderstand your requirements, I think you may be trying too hard. This works:

HTML

```
<img id="img1" src="http://dummyimage.com/100X100/000/fff" />
<div id="div1">This is text</div>
<img id="img2" src="http://dummyimage.com/100X100/000/fff" />
```

CSS

```
#div1 {
    display:inline;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znPP4/1/).

Comment: Well, I can't just put... text.. they're links, and other stuff. Not just text. I'm sorry for not precising that, I'll edit my question right now.

Comment: @DoorKnob, still pretty simple. Updated the code and the fiddle. Just put your text in an inline div.

Comment: Didn't work, I made the div containers and made them "inline". Literally did nothing.

Comment: @DoorKnob, that's because your images are **inside** the div you are making inline. Take the principles of my answer and use them. Work man, work :)

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, so I did what you did and it just ended up in a big mess. ([See the website](http://www.epilepticdev.tk))

Comment: @DoorKnob, there are several ways to skin this cat. This is as far as I have time to go right now. Just understand that you have a lot of CSS that is effecting how each element reacts. In my example, there is nothing else on the page to worry about. Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: why not create a span which is inline by default, rather creating a div and then giving it display:inline;

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by setting `float:left` and `float:right` to the images, and put the text at as last child of the container:

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="floatleft" src="http://www.epilepticdev.tk/screen.png" />
    <img class="floatright" src="http://www.epilepticdev.tk/sonl.png" />
    <div class="txt">
        <p>your text</p>
    </div>
</div>

.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.floatleft {
    float: left;
}
.floatright {
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6KwEZ/

Comment: I made a jsbin with this, and it just ends up in a very messy thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

html :

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/32x32" alt=""/>Test of text<img src="http://placehold.it/32x32" alt=""/>
</div>
```

css :

```
div {text-align:center}
div img {margin:0 5px;vertical-align:middle}
```

Example [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NUyVn/)

Comment: What part of :: If you don't understand the question, basically what I'm asking is how to do this:
-------webpage-------
[IMAGE] [TEXT] [IMAGE]
-------webpage-------  i didn't get ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code and convert inline css to your css.

```
<div>
    <div style="width:200px; float:left;">IMAGE</div>
    <div style="width:200px; float:left;">TEXT</div>
    <div style="width:200px; float:left;">IMAGE</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I just figured it out the easiest way. With margins. All I had to do was lower the `margin-top` to make it aligned with the text. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Cool. Can your write your solution and join it with your question ?

Answer (score -1):

Place all 3 elements within DIVs and float each div.
Should sort your problem.

Comment: I've already floated the two images to the left and right, text just won't seem to go between the images. How would I float it to the center?

Comment: Like I said. Place all 3 elements in a div - call it box or something then float each div left.

<div class="box">image</div>
<div class="box">text</div>
<div class="box">image</div>

.box {float:left;}